# Unable to run PHP file

Tags: php

Trying out PHP for the 1st time and trying to run a basic PHP program.

**The steps I followed:**

- Installed XAMPP and running Apache server on port 8080. (It says
  running on 443 and 8080)

[image]

- Then I go to *C:\xampp\htdocs* and create a    folder named php
  program and inside I create file named    *program.php*. The code:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        
        <?php
            echo "yeet";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

- Then I put the following in the browser with the Apache server
  running: *http://localhost/php%20program/program.php*

The result was:

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask]. It's very hard to help you debug something when you don't tell us what happens.

Comment: Sorry next time I will. It said unable to connect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default port for `http` is port `80`, but you said Apache was running on port `8080`. You need to be explicit in your URL when you are using a non-default port.

```
http://localhost:8080/php%20program/program.php
```